# ValueError: negative dimensions are not allowed - i don't know python, these always worked

Tags: python, jupyter

A old colleague left me a script that I always used without problems to get some information from our database. 
Today the script stopped working and I don't have any clue why.

I've already tried to run separate steps to identify where is the error. I'm currently learning python and I did some updates these week, but I have no idea why this stopped.

```
tissue_loads_sql = '''
SELECT
  gsp.load_num,
  gsp.carrier_cd,
  gsp.disp_date,
  gsi.whse_cd,
  gsp.f_dest_cd,
  cons_mkt.cons_mkt,
  cons_mkt.ma_descrip AS cons_market,
  gsp.del_terms,
  gsp.ship_mthd,
  gsi.load_type,
  goi.business_unit,
  Sum(gsi.load_net / 1000) AS net_tons,
  gsi.item_ord
FROM
  informix.gps_ship_item gsi
  INNER JOIN informix.gps_ship_plan gsp ON gsi.load_num = gsp.load_num
  INNER JOIN informix.gps_ord_item goi ON goi.item_ord = gsi.item_ord
  INNER JOIN informix.gps_cons_mkt cons_mkt ON cons_mkt.cons_mkt = goi.cons_mkt
WHERE
  gsp.load_num IN (SELECT DISTINCT
      ship_item.load_num
    FROM
      informix.gps_ship_item ship_item
      INNER JOIN informix.gps_ship_plan ship_plan ON ship_item.load_num = ship_plan.load_num
      INNER JOIN informix.gps_ord_item ord_item ON ord_item.item_ord = ship_item.item_ord
    WHERE
      ord_item.business_unit = 'TISSUE' AND
      ship_plan.disp_date BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-01-30')
GROUP BY
  gsp.load_num,
  gsp.carrier_cd,
  gsp.disp_date,
  gsi.whse_cd,
  gsp.f_dest_cd,
  cons_mkt.cons_mkt,
  cons_mkt.ma_descrip,
  gsp.del_terms,
  gsp.ship_mthd,
  gsi.load_type,
  goi.business_unit,
  gsi.item_ord
'''

df_loads = pd.read_sql_query(
    sql=tissue_loads_sql, con=dbcon, parse_dates=['disp_date'])
df_loads = df_loads.apply(
    lambda x: x.str.strip() if x.dtype == 'object' else x)

tissue_costs_sql = '''
SELECT
  gsic.load_num,
  Sum(gsic.valor_eur) AS cost_eur,
  gsic.item_ord
FROM
  informix.gps_ship_item_costs gsic
WHERE
  gsic.load_num IN (SELECT DISTINCT
      ship_item.load_num
    FROM
      informix.gps_ship_item ship_item
      INNER JOIN informix.gps_ship_plan ship_plan ON ship_item.load_num = ship_plan.load_num
      INNER JOIN informix.gps_ord_item ord_item ON ord_item.item_ord = ship_item.item_ord
    WHERE
      ord_item.business_unit = 'TISSUE' AND
      ship_plan.disp_date BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-01-30')
GROUP BY
  gsic.load_num,
  gsic.item_ord
'''

df_costs = pd.read_sql_query(sql=tissue_costs_sql, con=dbcon)
df_costs = df_costs.apply(
    lambda x: x.str.strip() if x.dtype == 'object' else x)



# THE ERROR OCCURS HERE: 

# merge dos dois dataframes
df = pd.merge(df_loads, df_costs, how='left', on=['load_num', 'item_ord'])
df['cost_eur'] = df['cost_eur'].fillna(0)

# extração de anos e meses
df['year'] = df['disp_date'].dt.year
df['month'] = df['disp_date'].dt.month

# eliminação de linhas do UWF
df = df[df['business_unit'] == 'TISSUE']

# factorização de algumas colunas
cols = ['whse_cd', 'ship_mthd', 'load_type']
for i in cols:
    df[i] = pd.Categorical(df[i])

# normalizar incoterms
df['incoterm'] = df['del_terms'].map(incoterm)

#WHEN I AGGREGATE IT GIVES AN ERROR

# agrupar registos
df = df.groupby([
    'load_num', 'carrier_cd', 'disp_date', 'whse_cd', 'f_dest_cd', 'cons_mkt',
    'cons_market', 'incoterm', 'ship_mthd', 'load_type', 'year', 'month'
]).agg({
    'net_tons': sum,
    'cost_eur': sum
}).reset_index()
```

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-baae0fe41359> in <module>
     24 ]).agg({
     25     'net_tons': sum,
---> 26     'cost_eur': sum
     27 }).reset_index()
     28 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\jose\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py in aggregate(self, arg, *args, **kwargs)
   1453     @Appender(_shared_docs["aggregate"])
   1454     def aggregate(self, arg=None, *args, **kwargs):
-> 1455         return super().aggregate(arg, *args, **kwargs)
   1456 
   1457     agg = aggregate

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\jose\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py in aggregate(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
    227         func = _maybe_mangle_lambdas(func)
    228 
--> 229         result, how = self._aggregate(func, _level=_level, *args, **kwargs)
    230         if how is None:
    231             return result

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\jose\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py in _aggregate(self, arg, *args, **kwargs)
    504 
    505                 try:
--> 506                     result = _agg(arg, _agg_1dim)
    507                 except SpecificationError:
    508 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\jose\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py in _agg(arg, func)
    454                 result = OrderedDict()
    455                 for fname, agg_how in arg.items():
--> 456                     result[fname] = func(fname, agg_how)
    457                 return result
    458 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\jose\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py in _agg_1dim(name, how, subset)
    438                         "nested dictionary is ambiguous " "in aggregation"
    439                     )
--> 440                 return colg.aggregate(how, _level=(_level or 0) + 1)
    441 
    442             def _agg_2dim(name, how):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\jose\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py in aggregate(self, func_or_funcs, *args, **kwargs)
    855             cyfunc = self._is_cython_func(func_or_funcs)
    856             if cyfunc and not args and not kwargs:
--> 857                 return getattr(self, cyfunc)()
    858 
    859             if self.grouper.nkeys > 1:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\jose\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in f(self, **kwargs)
   1375 
   1376                 # apply a non-cython aggregation
-> 1377                 result = self.aggregate(lambda x: npfunc(x, axis=self.axis))
   1378 
   1379                 # coerce the resulting columns if we can

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\jose\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py in aggregate(self, func_or_funcs, *args, **kwargs)
    858 
    859             if self.grouper.nkeys > 1:
--> 860                 return self._python_agg_general(func_or_funcs, *args, **kwargs)
    861 
    862             try:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\jose\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in _python_agg_general(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
    918                 output[name] = self._try_cast(values[mask], result)
    919 
--> 920         return self._wrap_aggregated_output(output)
    921 
    922     def _wrap_applied_output(self, *args, **kwargs):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\jose\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py in _wrap_aggregated_output(self, output, names)
    953             output=output, index=self.grouper.result_index, names=names
    954         )
--> 955         return self._reindex_output(result)._convert(datetime=True)
    956 
    957     def _wrap_transformed_output(self, output, names=None):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\jose\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in _reindex_output(self, output)
   2469         levels_list = [ping.group_index for ping in groupings]
   2470         index, _ = MultiIndex.from_product(
-> 2471             levels_list, names=self.grouper.names
   2472         ).sortlevel()
   2473 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\jose\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\multi.py in from_product(cls, iterables, sortorder, names)
    537 
    538         codes, levels = _factorize_from_iterables(iterables)
--> 539         codes = cartesian_product(codes)
    540         return MultiIndex(levels, codes, sortorder=sortorder, names=names)
    541 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\jose\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\util.py in cartesian_product(X)
     56             np.repeat(np.asarray(com.values_from_object(x)), b[i]), np.product(a[i])
     57         )
---> 58         for i, x in enumerate(X)
     59     ]

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\jose\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\util.py in <listcomp>(.0)
     56             np.repeat(np.asarray(com.values_from_object(x)), b[i]), np.product(a[i])
     57         )
---> 58         for i, x in enumerate(X)
     59     ]

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\jose\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py in repeat(a, repeats, axis)
    469 
    470     """
--> 471     return _wrapfunc(a, 'repeat', repeats, axis=axis)
    472 
    473 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\jose\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py in _wrapfunc(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
     54 def _wrapfunc(obj, method, *args, **kwds):
     55     try:
---> 56         return getattr(obj, method)(*args, **kwds)
     57 
     58     # An AttributeError occurs if the object does not have

ValueError: negative dimensions are not allowed
```